# CakePHP Multiple emails from one field

Tags: cakephp

I'm pretty new to cakephp, I did the sample posts tutorial on the website and I'm now working on my first project.
Its pretty simple. The administrator pastes a list of emails and they become records in the database with a random password.

1. So, I want to register multiple emails by inputting em 'foo@bar.com; bar@foo.com; com@foo.bar' style in the same textbox. In the database they should become a record/email. 
   For one email my code is: 
   echo $this -> Form -> input('email');
   echo $this -> Form -> input('code', array('default' => genRandomString()));
2. I also wan't to validate the adresses as emails later on. So could I use php's explode and then validate em on one way or another?

Greetings
Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cake itself has a neat method to explode them:

```
$emails = String::tokenize($emailList, ';');
```

( http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/string.html#string )

yes, you can iterate over them and manually validating them one by one or putting them into an array saveAll() understands and use 'validate'=>'first' or  'only' with it.

( http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html#validating-data-from-the-controller )

Comment: Ok so far. But how do I get this to work on the view layer? EmailList is not a part from the model. Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Vote.emailList' in 'field list'